# How do you add a Right Bar Button to a UINavigationController When the view has a nested Tabbar Controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to do something that should be fairly simple - add a right button to a UINavigationController, but for some reason the button is not showing up. I think the issue is the way my app is structured.
I have a Navigation Controller that Pushes a Tabbar Controller that contains my view that I want to add the right button on.
The code I'm using is:

```
UIBarButtonItem *editVehicle = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(onEditTapped)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editVehicle;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
self.tabBarController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
```

Comment: That worked, but why did it work? How did adding a right button to the tabbar end up adding a button to the NavigationController ? (thank you BTW)

Comment: Look, in normal situation (UINavigationController -> UIViewController) you call self.navigationItem. But in UITabBarController your hierarchy is like UINavigationController ->UITabBarController -> UIViewController. In this situation UITabbbar controller behavior like UIViewController in first situation so you have to call it from the upper view